# Different behaviour of CorePlot library on Iphone and Ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I'm trying to draw graph with CorePlot library version 1.5.1.It is ok when app runs on Ipad but when it runs on Iphone graph is not animating and following error appears in debug console

```
Assertion failure in -[CPTXYPlotSpace setXRange:], /Users/eskroch/Projects/Core Plot/framework/Source/CPTXYPlotSpace.m:377
```

Code for animating graph:

```
-(void)newData:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{
[Utils logClassObject:self andMethod:_cmd];
if(_beacon)
{
    CPTGraph *theGraph = layerHostingView.hostedGraph;
    CPTPlot *thePlot   = [theGraph plotWithIdentifier:kPlotIdentifier];

    if ( thePlot ) {
        if(_isDrawing)
        {
            if ( _arrayOfRSSI.count >= kMaxDataPoints ) {
                [_arrayOfRSSI removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                [_arrayOfTime removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                [thePlot deleteDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
            }

            CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)theGraph.defaultPlotSpace;
            NSUInteger location       = ([[_arrayOfTime lastObject] intValue] >= kMaxDataPoints ? [[_arrayOfTime lastObject] intValue] - kMaxDataPoints : 0);

            CPTPlotRange *oldRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger( (location > 0) ? location : 0 )
                                                                  length:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(kMaxDataPoints)];
            CPTPlotRange *newRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger((location>0 || ([[_arrayOfTime lastObject] intValue] >= kMaxDataPoints))?(location==0?5:location+5):location)
                                                                  length:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(kMaxDataPoints)];

            [CPTAnimation animate:plotSpace
                         property:@"xRange"
                    fromPlotRange:oldRange
                      toPlotRange:newRange
                         duration:CPTFloat(1.0 / 20)];


            [_arrayOfRSSI addObject:@(_beacon.rssi)];
            [_arrayOfTime addObject:@(currentIndex*5)];

            [thePlot insertDataAtIndex:_arrayOfRSSI.count - 1 numberOfRecords:1];
            AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
            [delegate.csvData appendFormat:@"%@;", _macAddress!=nil?[Utils stringToHex:_macAddress]:@"0"];

            [delegate.csvData appendFormat:@"%d;",5*currentIndex];
            [delegate.csvData appendFormat:@"%d;\n", (int)_beacon.rssi];
        }

        currentIndex++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Look at the call stack in Xcode after the assertion failure. Where did the crash occur? Was `-setXRange:` called from somewhere in your app or from something internal to Core Plot? Since the code you posted looks fine and it works on the iPad, I suspect there's an issue somewhere in the iPhone version of your app.

Comment: @EricSkroch thanks I found solution from your comment to issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where was the problem.There was [an issue with same type of problem](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/77) ,so when I did like it was said in the comment for that issue and downloaded new version of library everything worked as it was expected